# Doubt in Euler's proof Basel problem

Tags: summation, euler-sums

In the proof of the Basel problem Euler reaches a step where expansion of $(\sin x)/x$ is $[1-(x^2/\pi^2)][1-(x^2/4\pi^2)][1-(x^2/9\pi^2)]\cdots$
And from that he got to-
$1- x^2\{1/\pi^2 + (1/4\pi^2) + (1/9\pi^2) +\cdots\}+ x^4(\cdots)+\cdots$.
I don't understand how this happens?

Comment: It comes from the second derivative at $x=0$. To make this rigorous you need some complex analysis to [show](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf) $\pi \cot (\pi z) = \lim_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n=-N}^N \frac{1}{z+n}$.

Comment: Well, what do you get as the coefficient of $x^2$ when you multiply everything out?

Comment: But how do we multiply "everything" when we have to multiply infinite "things"?

Comment: Well x^2 will be preserved only if the term containing x^2 is multiplied by 1.

Comment: Yes, you have to take the $x^2$ term from one bracket and the $1$ term from each of the other brackets, and all but one of the infinitely many things you are multiplying is $1$, so it's OK.

Comment: So, 167920, are we OK?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes I do believe so. Thanks for your help

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem#Euler's_approach) explanation on Wikipedia and some generalizations.